# Is the window manager handling Wine applications differently?

Tags: unity, gnome, wine, compiz, mutter

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this; perhaps it is a bug.

On some applications that a launched using Wine, if you switch window focus away from them, you cannot get the focus back. For example if I am playing a game like The Sims 3 and I alt-tab, hit the Super-key, or do alt-up arrow, I cannot get back to the Wine application window. It shows the application in Unity or Gnome shell but when I select it by alt-tabbing to it, or simply clicking on it, it just shows the desktop background. I took a video of it and uploaded it here - http://youtu.be/EiVlX4yBTVg

The steps I followed to cause this condition are as follows:

1. Launch an application using a 3rd party launcher (like Steam or Origin)
2. Wait for the application to fully load
3. Alt-tab out of the application
4. Try to focus back onto the application

I tested this with both Compiz and the Gnome Shell and the results are the exact same.